# How can I dynamically change text based on input field?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I dynamically change a link based upon an input field in a form. For example, if I input `1.00` into the input field, I want to change the link to this:

`donate.php?amount=1.00`

Where the amount changes to the amount specified in the input field.

I'm guessing its JavaScript which isn't my strongest point but any help would be awesome. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

markup:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" onkeyup="changeLink(this);" />
<a href="donate.php?amount=0.0" id="donateLink"> donate now! </a>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeLink(inputElement)
{
    $('#donateLink').attr("href","donate.php?amount="+inputElement.value);
    //console.log($('#donateLink').attr("href"));
}
```

[jsfiddle working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LpQTB/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this dude, it means a lot to me :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with html forms:

```
<form action="donate.php" method="GET" id="donateform">
    <input type="text" name="amount" />
    <input type="submit" value="Donate" />
</form>
```

You could also have input entered via a drop down list so they don't enter invalid values. Or you could validate the input with javascript. To use a link to submit the form, you can use javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['donateform'].submit();">Donate</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, just use a form. By using the GET method with a form and naming your input field 'amount', that will already be added to the URL at the time of form submission. Go ahead and try submitting a form when you enter `1.00` into the box. When the page loads, your URL will be `donate.php?amount=1.00` like expected. The URL does not need to be changed whatsoever.

If you're using POST, I would merely suggest *not* doing this. It serves no purpose in that case.